# Как сделать UPDATE перед удалением записей

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELETE FROM user_todo_send 
    WHERE id_user IN 
        (SELECT tempT.id_user FROM 
            ( SELECT uts.id_user AS id_user FROM user_todo_send uts 
                INNER JOIN todo ON todo.id = uts.id_todo 
                WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, NOW(),  todo.time_created) > uts.time) AS tempT)
```

Вот такой запрос я использую для удаления через JOIN, но теперь возникла необходимость еще и UPDATE делать в таблице todo при JOIN, возможно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте требуемый UPDATE в триггер на удаление из таблицы user_todo_send

Примерно так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_user_todo_send ` before delete ON `user_todo_send`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  update todo set ...что меняем... where id in (...получение ID требуемых записей)... END
```

к полям удаляемых записей user_todo_send можно обращаться через алиас OLD. Например: `OLD.id_user` вернет id_user удаляемой записи.

Comment: не понимаю как это сделать ... можно хоть какой-то пример реализации